# Creating a seat map with unknown rows/columns (or: GridView auto generated columns not as text?)

Tags: asp.net, charts

I want to have a seating chart, with clickable ImageButtons that show if the seat is taken or not.
The thing is, the amount of rows/columns depends on the selected theater.

So far, I have a DataTable filled with 0's for empty seats and 1's in taken seats.
This DataTable gets filled according to the rows/columns of the theater, and then 1's are placed by a Access table with all the taken seats (tickets).

I found two ways to show this DataTable:
**A GridView, with *AutoGenerateColumns="true"***
The problem with this is that it automatically generates as plain text while I want ImageButtons.

**A Table control, and on Page_Load I create it using loops and fill it's cells with ImageButtons**
The problem here is that the ImageButtons (while showing the right image) don't respond to clicks, since I can't call ImageButton1_OnClick and the like, and using a CommandName also showed no results.

The code that fills the Table control:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Showing show = (Showing)Session["show"];

    DataTable dt = DB.GetShowingSeats(show); //gets a table filled with 0's and 1's

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        TableRow Trow = new TableRow();

        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
        {
            TableCell Tcell = new TableCell();
            ImageButton btn = new ImageButton();

            btn.CommandName = "btnClick";    //doesn't work
            btn.OnClientClick = "btn_Click";  //also doesn't work

            if ((string)row[col] == "0")
            {
                btn.ImageUrl = "~/images/empty.png";
            }
            else
            {
                btn.ImageUrl = "~/images/taken.png";
                btn.Enabled = false;
            }

            Tcell.Controls.Add(btn);
            Trow.Cells.Add(Tcell);
        }

        this.tableSeats.Rows.Add(Trow);
    }
}
```

So basically, either somehow have buttons in the Table have an OnClick event (and also I need to know the row/column of the button clicked)
**OR**
I can change the AutoGenerateColumns make the columns with ImageButtons instead of text (if not possible, is there a way I can "auto" generate my own columns on Page_Load?)

Answer (score 0):

I would just

- Loop through your [`DataTable.Columns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.columns.aspx) collection,
- Create an [`ImageField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagefield.aspx) object for each of the columns in your datasource
- Add that `ImageField` to your [`GridView.Columns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.columns.aspx) collection.
- Bind your `DataTable` to the `GridView`.

Here is some sample code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable tbl = generateTable(); // A table of 1's an 0's
    foreach (DataColumn col in tbl.Columns)
    {
        ImageField img = new ImageField();
        img.DataImageUrlField = col.ColumnName;
        // I have 2 images in my "/Images" folder, 1.jpg and 0.jpg.
        img.DataImageUrlFormatString = "/Images/{0}.jpg";
        GridView1.Columns.Add(img);
    }
    GridView1.DataSource = tbl;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

The only caveat to this is that it depends on your `DataTable` columns having a ColumnName.  It can be whatever (in this sample, mine are just integers).  This way you can use databinding to bind the `ImageField`s to your `DataTable` columns.

---

For reference, here is the code that I used to generate the table

```
// Generates a 10 x 10 table of 1's and 0's
public DataTable generateTable()
{
    DataTable tbl = new DataTable("seats");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        tbl.Columns.Add(i.ToString());
    }
    Random rand = new Random();
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        DataRow row = tbl.NewRow();
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            row[j] = rand.Next(10) > 5 ? 0 : 1;
        }
        tbl.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    return tbl;
}
```